# can multiple server access the same mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-load-balancer

I am going to create a load balancer in Azure. I have a VM that already running and going to take a backup of the existing VM and will create another VM using that backup. So two servers will have the same configuration and will use the same credentials.
In the already existing server, I have MongoDB configured, and if I create the same VM that will also have the same configuration as the old VM. Now what I want to know is can I use the same MongoDB which will be accessed by two servers that have the same configurations?

Will it create any mess or any give any error?

can I use like above mentioned?

Do I need to configure another MongoDB for the second server?

can anyone please clarify my questions? it would be great to have some clear explanation. thank you

Comment: I suggest reading mongodb docs about building replica sets (the official way to support mongodb on multiple machines). Also, note that this is off-topic here (not programming-related). If it's just about accessing a single mongodb vm/server from multiple client machines: yes, you can do that - that's by design (and you wouldn't have much of a database system if it could only communicate with a single client).

Comment: The answer is YES. As many servers as possible will have access to your DB as long as they are provided with the right credentials.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has build in support for horizontal scalability and high availability meaning that you dont need to create a 3th party load balancer , the mongos service part of mongoDB sharding cluster is the load balancer itself. Check the official documentation for mongoDB replication and sharding ...

On your questions:

Will it create any mess or any give any error?

If you just copy data to another VM it will be fine , as far as you dont write to one of the VMs you can loadbalance reads between this independent VMs , but this is strange approch when you have build in mongoDB replication mechanism and you can just add the second VM as a SECONDARY member from replicaSet.

can I use like above mentioned?

Sure , you can use also this approach but why you will need to do it?

Do I need to configure another MongoDB for the second server?

Depends on the use case , but in general you would prefer to create 3x members replicaSet  or if your database is large and write performance is strong requirement you may need to distribute the database between multiple servers ( shards ) so you will need more then just 3x servers ...